# why do the tasks in celery chain execute out of order?

Tags: python

I have four time-consuming tasks which should execute one by one and the result from previous task can be the input of the next one. So I choose Celery chain to do this. And I do this exampled by the follow code:

```
mychain = chain(task1.s({'a': 1}), task2.s(), task3.s(), task4.s())
mychain.apply_async()
```

But the execute order of the tasks is:

```
enter code here`task1() ---> task4() ---> task3() --->task2()
```

I don't know what happen.

I run a web server by tornado, and it woke up the tasks by chain.

logging:

```
[2018-07-23 18:34:12,816][pid:25557][tid:140228657469056][util.py:109] DEBUG: chain: fetch({}) | callback() | convert() | format()
```

the other tasks run in celery

logging:

```
[2018-07-23 18:34:12,816: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: fetch[045acf81-274b-457c-8bb5-6d0248264b76]
[2018-07-23 18:34:17,786: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: format[103b4ffa-57db-4b04-a745-7dfee5786695]
[2018-07-23 18:34:18,227: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: convert[81ddbaf9-37b3-406a-b608-a05affa97f45]
[2018-07-23 18:34:20,942: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: callback[b1ea7c70-db45-4501-9859-7ad22532c38a]
```

Comment: Give your minimal code we can reproduce, `chain` works well with sequence in my local.

Comment: We try chain in local machine, it works. In fact, what we do is a web server running in a machine and some comsuming task running with celery running in others and they communicate by sending some message and data to redis. So I doubt that the problem is in the communication between the web server and task' machine. But I can't find them and I could't give your minimal code~

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the celery version of the two machines is different!
And then we set the same celery version, they work!